# ASP.NET Core 2.2 app won't run on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I have a really simple ToDo demo application that I upgraded from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core 2.1. The application runs locally without errors.

When I do a Right Click Publish to an Azure Web App I get the following error:

```
This xxxx.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found.
No webpage was found for the web address: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

When I publish a *File -> New* Project application it runs successfully. I've compared the output of both applications and my ToDo app uses more dependencies but overall they look pretty similar.

I've enabled diagnostics for both the application and the web server but I don't see any errors in the log.

How do I debug this? Where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

After enabling [ASP.NET Core Module stdout log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log), the stdout log showed that the app was trying to connect to a LocalDB database which of course wasn't available. Fixing the connection string to point to a SQL Azure database solved the issue.

I would have expected an HTTP 500 error since this clearly is an issue in my application. I still don't understand why a 404 was returned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the .net 5 API project. It works fine on local machine but after publishing to Azure WebApp it gives the error

```
 This ****.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found.
 No webpage was found for the web address: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/ HTTP ERROR 404
```

In my case following lines were missing from Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }
        );
```

Adding these lines in the configuration section of the startup.cs fixed the issue.